Three brothers fighting a dark queen/witch
Alright, I have no idea if this is answerable, but it's driving me up a wall that I can't find this movie.
Some time ago, I found a movie on YouTube that was about three brothers pitted against a dark queen/witch. It plays out like a Disney movie. The brothers are very comical. In the beginning, a boar or troll or some sort of beast attacks their tribe/village, and they're tripping over each other trying to get in armor to fight this beast.
After they defeat the beast, a dark queen/witch is shown being carried away in a palanquin, back to her palace. The entire region is very much like a desert, with many cliffs and no trees in sight.
The animation style was very similar to Emperor's New Groove, but with brighter colors and smoother animations. If I was to estimate when I saw it, it would be 2011-2012. I believe it was between 2 1/2 to 3 1/2 hours long.
Also worth mentioning that when I watched half this movie, it was a Russian/Ukrainian dub. There was definitely Cyrillic in the title.

Can you estimate the year?

If I were to estimate the year, I would guess 2011-2012. Sorry, should have known to include that from my last question.

One further question. When you say a movie on YouTube, was this professional produced, or was it some amateurish film that just had decent animation?

It was a professional film, definitely not amateur. It had opening credits, but I can't for the life of me remember a single one, otherwise I'd be looking it up by studio name etc. etc.

Was it feature length, or just a short movie?

A long shot if this was some time ago, but if you're logged into Youtube, you can search the film in your viewing history. It archives every video you've ever watched.

It was three hours long. That may be why it was taken down from YouTube. I remember because I watched half of it, then when I went to finish it, I couldn't find it (even if I had the URL, I could have done a cache search on that...).

Is it "How Not To Rescue A Princess"? Trailer here
A russian film:

A magical Princess in search of the Fountain of Youth enlists the help of her faithful crow sidekick and three famous but crazy knights to guide and protect her on a perilous journey filled with mysterious creatures and wild adventures.


I think you're onto something. There's a bunch of recent animated Russian films with these 3 heroes (called The Three Bogatyrs). So even if this isn't the right film, the OP might be after one of them.

"The Three Bogatyrs and the Shamakhan Queen" is the alternative name for "How Not To Rescue A Princess". It's got an evil princess in a desert and it's the right year.

Yeah, but apparently its runtime is 75 minutes (so says the internet, anyway).

I assumed that the OP had been mistaken in how long it was. Can't really tell either way until they return though.

Yes, 100% this is it. The beginning is almost exactly as I remember, especially with the Queen in her palanquin. I couldn't find all three Bogatyrs fighting a single enemy, but I guess I'll just have to watch it again! I even found a playlist of all the movies on YouTube. Thank you.
